# Salesforce limits on sending email in one hour

Tags: email, opportunity, governorlimits, limits, singleemailmessage

One of the user send an important email from an opportunity record to the team members. We can see the email message record in the related list but non of the team members received the email.

I want to know how many emails can a user send in one hour from Salesforce? I read it is 250 emails but I am not sure if it is 250/user/org or is it 250/org for all the users in the org? Also, when I generate an email log, it only show the list of successfully send emails. Is there anyway we can see the list/log of emails that were not send from Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

This limit is per user as per [the doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.allocations_email_general.htm&type=5)

> Single Email Limits
>
> Each licensed org can send single emails to a maximum of 5,000 external email addresses, or recipients, per day. A day is based on Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).
>
> Sending emails to internal email recipients doesn't count toward the org daily limit.
>
> For orgs created before Spring ’19, the org daily limit is enforced only for emails sent via Apex and Salesforce APIs, except for REST API.
> For orgs created in Spring ’19 and later, the org daily limit is also enforced for email alerts, simple email actions, Send Email actions in flows, and REST API.
>
> ***Each user*** can send emails from the email composer to a maximum of 250 external email recipients per hour.

### Monitor limits

[Check the Single Email Message Limit](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386230&type=1)

Use the REST explorer in Workbench

```
/services/data/v58.0/limits
```